# Landscape autopilot installation problem

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I have tried for several times installing landscape openstack using autopilot. But I'm receiving errors with the last two steps in installing region on cloud (configure availability zones and neutron network). 
I'm using virtual machines on Ubuntu Virt-manager and MAAS. To go to the installation step I first need to have two networks in MAAS, and during configuring them again I have to delete one and have just public network. Can this be a problem?

Last time after starting of installation i have added again my private network to MAAS and these are logs of the errors:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/10579745/

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you shouldn't have to change the networking between the checklist and the configuration pages.

Since you are using VMs, let's try something simple to begin with.

First, make sure your VMs have enough RAM. The bootstrap node, that's the machine with 2 NICs, will need at least 4Gb, maybe 8Gb, since it will host all the administrative services like mysql, rabbit and others. All the rest should have ideally 2Gb or more. I'm being conservative here, since I know these are VMs and you seem to be just testing things out before moving on to a more real deployment. Even 2Gb might not be enough. For a real deployment I would expect all nodes to have at least 16Gb of RAM.

Have only one network, and plug all NICs to it. For the VM that has two NICs, plug both of them to the same network. Like in this image:

[image: AutoPilot flat network]

You can see that one node has both NICs connected to the same network. Delete all your MAAS nodes and enlist them again in this configuration.

When configuring this network in MAAS, divide it in three pieces:  dynamic range, static range and a range reserved for floating IPs. MAAS only cares about the first two, but leave room for the floating IPs that OpenStack will want later on.

For more details, please see the following Q/A:

- [How should I setup MAAS so that it can be used by the Canonical OpenStack Autopilot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/595558)

Comment: I'm having everything contracted using 24Gb of RAM in my server. And for each machine I have made 4Gb. Hope this will be enough. During installation htop show 17Gb used. Thanks for tip with network. Try to do it now. Will post the results.

Comment: Can you tell me if I'm wrong or not. I have my maas controller in virtual network 10.17.17.0/24 (ip: 10.17.17.200). I have placed 5 pc in this network. and in maas cluster manage interface is with the static interface: 10.17.17.200. router ip - 10.17.17.1.
Also i have created network in MAAS: 10.17.17.0/24. With this parameters i cannot go through vSwitch configuration... Can your explain about network features more carefull, please

Comment: I posted a more complete answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/595558/how-should-i-setup-maas-so-that-it-can-be-used-by-the-canonical-openstack-autopi/

Comment: So flat network works good with vSwitch configuration. Thank you. Hope will finish installation successfully!

Comment: Thanks. The problem was with network because of the MAAS version.. I was installing ubuntu server with MAAS. That was bad idea=)